# Multiple repeating regions on one texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am wondering if I could texture the exterior of a simple house with just this texture:[image]

Basically, I want the shingles texture to repeat on the roof, and I want the white wall part to repeat on the walls.  The door and window textures will be on the doors and windows.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just connect the output of the texture node coordinate 'uv' to a mod node, and then to an add node(all found in converter>vector math), with the mod vector set to the size of the window, and the add vector set to the position of the window, like such:
[image]

However, its probably better to just use a single texture for each, as it will be much easier, and if you want to export it you'll need to.

It is also possible to do this with only one material by specifying the offset with a second UV map.
You can do this by creating a second UV map, found under UV maps in the object data properties. Then,you can UV unwrap the faces for each part, and scale them to zero, making it a single point for all of those faces. You can then move this point to the start of the patterns in the image:
[image]
and connect the output of the second UV map to the offset, like such:
[image]
which allows for only one material.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to achieve this effect with just one material?

Comment: @TheHyperStar123 , It is, I updated my post.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.

Comment: I will continue to experiment with this method of repeating textures and get it to look as good as possible.